# Controlling WCF response format and namespaces

Tags: c#, wcf

I want my WCF response to have a response element with two namespaces using DataContracts, but I can't get it to work. This is what I would like the response to be:

```xml
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <s:Header />
  <s:Body>
    <ns2:TestReply xmlns="http://www.test.org/test/2007/00" xmlns:ns2="http://www.test2.org/test2/types">
      <ns2:Result>
        <ns2:ActionSuccessful>true</ns2:ActionSuccessful>
      </ns2:Result>
      <ns2:ResultData>
        <ns2:Name>Maikel Willemse</ns2:Name>
      </ns2:ResultData>
    </ns2:TestReply>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

This is the response I get (when testing with the WCF Test Client):

```xml
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header />
  <s:Body>
    <GetDataResponse xmlns="http://www.test.org/test/2007/00">
      <TestReply xmlns:a="http://www.test2.org/test2/types" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <a:Result>
          <a:ActionSuccessful>true</a:ActionSuccessful>
        </a:Result>
        <a:ResultData>
          <a:Name>Maikel Willemse</a:Name>
        </a:ResultData>
      </TestReply>
    </GetDataResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

My service interface looks like this:

```cs
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://www.test.org/test/2007/00")]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    [return: MessageParameter(Name = "TestReply")]
    GetDataResponse GetData(string name);
}
```

The service class:

```cs
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public GetDataResponse GetData(string name)
    {
        return new GetDataResponse
            {
                Result = new Result {ActionSuccessful = true},
                ResultData = new ResultData {Name = name}
            };
    }
}
```

And the DataContract classes are:

```cs
[DataContract(Namespace = "http://www.test2.org/test2/types")]
public class GetDataResponse
{
    [DataMember(Name = "Result")]
    public Result Result { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "ResultData")]
    public ResultData ResultData { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(Namespace = "http://www.test2.org/test2/types")]
public class Result
{
    [DataMember(Name = "ActionSuccessful")]
    public bool ActionSuccessful { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(Namespace = "http://www.test2.org/test2/types")]
public class ResultData
{
    [DataMember(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The target framework of my WCF project is .NET 4. The namespace prefixes do not have to be the same. How can I get the response in the format I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To @Maikel
The TestReply is in the default namespace so there is no prefix, but the elements inside do have it.

```
xmlns:a="http://www.test2.org/test2/types
```

so the prefix for this namespace is a. (because of 'a=') and it is different from the default namespace.

In the ServiceContractAttribute of your method

```
GetDataResponse GetData(string name);
```

as @Carlos suggested, you can write

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace="http://www.test2.org/test2/types")]
```

You cannot have this

```
<a:TestReply xmnls:a="http://www.test2.org/test2/types">
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to remove the "wrapping" element from the response, you'll need to use a `[MessageContract]`. The code below shows one way how it can be done. And you can play with the namespaces in the service / message / data contracts to match what you want.

```
public class StackOverflow_15173138
{
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://www.test.org/test/2007/00")]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        MyResponse GetData(MyRequest request);
    }

    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public MyResponse GetData(MyRequest request)
        {
            return new MyResponse
            {
                TestReply = new GetDataResponse
                {
                    Result = new Result { ActionSuccessful = true },
                    ResultData = new ResultData { Name = request.name }
                }
            };
        }
    }

    [MessageContract(IsWrapped = false)]
    public class MyResponse
    {
        [MessageBodyMember]
        public GetDataResponse TestReply { get; set; }
    }

    [MessageContract(WrapperName = "GetData")]
    public class MyRequest
    {
        [MessageBodyMember]
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract(Namespace = "http://www.test2.org/test2/types")]
    public class GetDataResponse
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "Result")]
        public Result Result { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "ResultData")]
        public ResultData ResultData { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract(Namespace = "http://www.test2.org/test2/types")]
    public class Result
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "ActionSuccessful")]
        public bool ActionSuccessful { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract(Namespace = "http://www.test2.org/test2/types")]
    public class ResultData
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public static void Test()
    {
        string baseAddress = "http://" + Environment.MachineName + ":8000/Service";
        ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service1), new Uri(baseAddress));
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService1), new BasicHttpBinding(), "");
        host.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceMetadataBehavior { HttpGetEnabled = true });
        host.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Host opened");

        ChannelFactory<IService1> factory = new ChannelFactory<IService1>(new BasicHttpBinding(), new EndpointAddress(baseAddress));
        IService1 proxy = factory.CreateChannel();
        Console.WriteLine(proxy.GetData(new MyRequest { name = "hello" }));

        ((IClientChannel)proxy).Close();
        factory.Close();

        Console.Write("Press ENTER to close the host");
        Console.ReadLine();
        host.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, it's almost what I want. The lay-out of the XML is exactly how I want it, but the <TestReply> element does not have the "a:" prefix... Any ideas?

Comment: There's no simple way to customize the *prefixes* in the XML generated by WCF - the prefix should be used to define the namespace only, and you usually don't get to pick which prefix is used. If you really want to customize them, you can do it, but it's not trivial - the post at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2010/06/13/changing-prefixes-in-xml-responses.aspx shows one way of doing it.

Comment: I'm sorry, that's not what I meant. I don't mind the prefix being "a", but I would like the <TestReply> node (so the first child node of the body) to have it as well: <a:TestReply ...>. When using your code, all nodes inside <TestReply> have the prefix (which is good), but the <TestReply> node itself doesn't.