# Set custom tag in WSDL + WCF

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap, wsdl

Is possible to convert this fragment of wsdl:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:com="http://com.lsc.services.financialSystem">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <com:crearCuentaPorCobrar>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <com:crearCuentaPorCobrarRq>
            <com:infoRequest>
               <com:RequestID>?</com:RequestID>
               <com:Fecha>?</com:Fecha>
               <com:AplicacionCliente>?</com:AplicacionCliente>
               <com:Terminal>?</com:Terminal>
               <com:IP>?</com:IP>
            </com:infoRequest>
          </com:crearCuentaPorCobrarRq>
      </com:crearCuentaPorCobrar>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

To this solution:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:com="http://com.lsc.services.financialSystem">
       <soapenv:Header/>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <com:crearCuentaPorCobrar>
             <!--Optional:-->
             <crearCuentaPorCobrarRq>
                <infoRequest>
                   <RequestID>?</com:RequestID>
                   <Fecha>?</com:Fecha>
                   <AplicacionCliente>?</com:AplicacionCliente>
                   <Terminal>?</com:Terminal>
                   <IP>?</com:IP>
                </infoRequest>
              </crearCuentaPorCobrarRq>
          </com:crearCuentaPorCobrar>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

You can observe that in the second WSDL I don't want to use the index: 'com' to its subitems, only in its container (crearCuentaPorCobrar). I observe another posts like: [Controlling WCF response format and namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15173138/controlling-wcf-response-format-and-namespaces) but this is not mi interest to establish more code on wsdl.

There is a way to build this???

Thk a lot!!!

Comment: Your second WSDL still has `com:` in the closing tags. It's invalid.

Comment: Yeah.... this is the idea... i wanna only crearCuentaPorCobrar with 'com'

Comment: I meant that you have `<RequestID>?</com:RequestID>`, see the com: in there :P

Comment: ohhh sorry.... is without com, like this 

<infoRequest>
                   <RequestID>?</RequestID>
                   <Fecha>?</Fecha>
                   <AplicacionCliente>?</AplicacionCliente>
                   <Terminal>?</Terminal>
                   <IP>?</com:IP>
                </infoRequest>
    </soapenv:Envelope>